# django form with multiple choice field with potentially infinite choices

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, manytomanyfield

I have a model with a [many-to-many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) field that will expand as the user adds more entries for the model. In the form template if I use the conventional `{{ form.field }}` I get a multiple choice select as is expected, but the problem that will quickly become apparent is when there are 10, 100, 1000 or more choices. What I'd like to provide in the form is a search field where the user can search through all available entries and via AJAX return entries matching their search criteria where they can then select the individual entry choices to be saved in the database.

I'm assuming I will have to manually render the multiple choice form field, but after hours of research I cannot find an example of this anywhere online. Is there an example that exists and I just haven't been able to find? How is one supposed to manually create a form with a multiple choice field in Django? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: Are the [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/) the thing you're looking for?

Comment: I think OP wants to have "search and add" function with large records as potential choices.

Comment: I don't think so because it says formsets are an "abstraction to work with multiple forms on the same page", but I'm working with a single form with a multiple choice field.

Comment: Do you need something like https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects ?

Comment: Why not use some simple plugin from jquery autocomplete? http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple

Comment: @diegueus9 I will look into that. Based on what I quickly read I'm not sure if it's compatible with how I have searching implemented. I am using haystack with elasticsearch.

Comment: @E-rich but is a good beginning

Comment: You could have a look at select2 plugin: https://select2.github.io/